# Updating DATE field in MySQL database table

Tags: python, mysql, date

Not able  to update DATE field in MySql Database.Here is the code i used:

```
def update_date(self):
    self.cursor.execute("""SELECT  min(date),rec_id FROM mytable1 GROUP BY rec_id;""")
    data=self.cursor.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        open_dt=row[0]
        pr_id=row[1]
        if open_dt:
            open_dt= open_dt.date()
            print open_dt,pr_id
            self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE mytable2 rec_open_date=%s WHERE rec_id=%d;"""%(open_dt,rec_id))
        else:
            pass
```

I have made all the necessary imports and DB connection is also working. When i run the code it runs with a warning:

```
Warning: Out of range value for column 'rec_open_date' at row 1
  self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE mytable2 SET rec_open_date=%s WHERE rec_id=%d;""" %(open_dt,rec_id))
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: See the above details. On running it just prompts a warning and when i check the database it updates rec_open_date to 0000-00-00 for all records

Comment: Your error is talking about `calc_study_open_dt`, but you are talking about `rec_open_date`?

Comment: My bad....!!! I did an edit...U can check now

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) you will see that the `execute` method calls for a separate data argument, not format the string using `%`.

Try:

```
self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE mytable2 rec_open_date=%s WHERE rec_id=%s""",
                    (open_dt, rec_id))
```

What you did instead was executing this

```
UPDATE mytable2 rec_open_date=2011-02-03 12:34:56 WHERE rec_id=1;
```

Which is not a valid statement, but for whatever reason something executed.  Also, using `%` is a security flaw that permits SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @user3747506 it is not working doesn't tell me anything.  Can you try printing out the values of open_dt and rec_id and include that in your question?  Also consider dropping that last `;`.  I updated my answer.

Comment: query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: Oh, whoops, that last `%d` should have been a `%s`.  My answer is now fixed.

Comment: @user3747506 is there anything else that stops this from working?  If it's working you should accept the answer.